# EDSDK [Cacon SDK] saving files to Directory. On Close will not delete files within the directory

Tags: c#, wpf, process, sdk

I am using the Canon SDK for taking photos and storing them into a directory. When closing the window (Have tried Window_Closed and Window_Closing events) I want to clear these photos. I am receiving a warning that the files I am trying to remove are still being used in a process and can't find a working solution.

This is my code I am running:

```
sdk.Dispose();

        System.IO.DirectoryInfo imageDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(sTempImageDirectory);

        foreach (FileInfo file in imageDirectory.GetFiles())
        {
            File.Delete(file.FullName);
        }
```

Comment: How are you saving the byte array from the camera to disk? Sounds like the file is not closed properly after download.

Comment: I am only using a file directory the image points to to create and name in that space. It is a closing issue that I am not doing right. Just can't figure it out. The app removed the files from the last instance it was ran (or prior if there are any through testing) but as long as the images were not taken in the current instance, they will be removed.